# Solving equation containing integrals with python

Tags: python, scipy, equation, integral

I'm currently trying to solve the following equation for x:

3.17e-2 - integral from x to 215 of [(10.^(8.64/x) / (480.1 - 10.^(4.32/x))^2)]dx = 0.

(sorry for writing the equation in such a crude way, I wasn't sure on how to insert latex on here)
so far I've come up with this:

```
import scipy as s
from scipy.integrate import odeint,quad
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    fpe = 40
    k = 1.26e4*fpe**2/4.2e4
    return 10.**(8.64/x) / (k - 10.**(4.32/x))**2

def intf(x):
    for i in x:
        if 3.17e-2 - quad(lambda i:f(i),i,215) == 0.:
            print(i)



xi = np.linspace(0.01, 5, 1000)
intf(xi)
```

However, I keep getting the following error:
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')

As you can imagine, this is not the result I was expecting. Do you reckon that this is only due to the result being too large or could there be something wrong with the code?

Comment: have you checked out sagemath it has all math functionality.

Comment: `f(0.01)` gives the overflow. Looking at the definition of `f`, you have `10**860` on the first term, for `x = 0.01`, which is a pretty large number (the maximum value a double can represent is around 10^308, so you are way above that).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you have to change [quad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) returns a tuple `(y, abserr)`, the result of the integral is `quad(...)[0]`

Also, if you compare `f(x) == 0` you will only detect exact solutions, that will be impossible for this function in floating point computation. You could use `abs(f(x)) < ytol`, or simply use a zero finding method. I would suggest you to use [fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)

Another thing is that you have the derivative of the function, so you can pass that to the fsolve as well, putting all together you have

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def fprime(x):
    fpe = 40
    k = 1.26e4*fpe**2/4.2e4
    return 10.**(8.64/x) / (k - 10.**(4.32/x))**2
def f(x):
    try:
        return np.array([f(i) for i in x])
    except TypeError:
        return 3.17e-2 - quad(lambda i:fprime(i),x,215)[0]

from scipy.optimize import fsolve
x0 = fsolve(f, 1, fprime=fprime)
```

this gives `x0=2.03740802`, and `f(x0) = 2.35922393e-16`

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful!

Comment: Would you mind explaining to me what the 1 and fprime=fprime do as arguments of fsolve? I couldn't find anything similar in the documentation

Comment: [fprime=callable](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html#:~:text=arguments%20to%20func.-,fprime,-callable%20f(x)), in this case the callable is the function fprime defined just after the imports.

If it solves for you, please follow the instruction in the site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), to indicate that. Thank you.